# Rigid bodies stick to root

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I tried to make an animation where meshes fall down like dominos.

[image]

But as seen in the picture, the stones just rotate about their origin point and snap back to their original position, nothing falls down or continues.

How do I get them to actually fall down?

Comment: The first thing is, as @LeonardoCáceres mentions the origin of your object is not centered in your geometry. Changing this should be sufficient to fix your problem so this is a good answer. The other thing is just a tip: with simple objects like these, the simulations calculate faster and more accurate when you choose appropiate _Collision Shapes_. Instead of _Convex Hull_, you could use _Box_  for the stones and _Sphere_ for the ball. Also make sure that all your objects have their scales applied with _Ctrl+A > Apply > Scale_, because incorrect scales can cause simulation problems as well.

Answer (score 6):

In your scene I see that your domino objects have the origin at the bottom, in physics the origin works as the center of mass so when the origin is down all the weight of the object also goes down. Put the origin back to the center of the object and that should fix the problem.

[image]